# How to multiply N amount of floats using recursion?

Tags: recursion, ada

I'm practicing recursive problems for upcoming exams and have gotten stuck on this problem.

The program is supposed to take N amount of floats and multiply them together, all using recursion.

Example:
The user inputs 2, then the program will take 2 floats from the user, say for example 2.0 and 3.0. Then the result is 6.0.

My attempted solution is the code below. The core problem that I have is that I don't know how I'm supposed to multiply the floats together in a way that works.
Right now all my program does is that it takes N amount of floats and then just prints the last one without multiplying them all together. I do feel like the solution is simple but I really cannot find it. Would love some help on this one, thanks in advance.

```ada
    with Ada.Text_IO;         use Ada.Text_IO;
    with Ada.Integer_Text_IO; use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
    with Ada.Float_Text_IO;   use Ada.Float_Text_IO;

    procedure Recprac3 is
       ---------------------------------- 
       procedure Calc(N : in Integer;
                    F : out Float) is
          Prod : Float;
       begin
          if N = 0 then
             Put("The product is: ");
             Put(Prod, 2, 2, 0);       -- 2, 2, 0 is formatting
          else                        
             Get(F);
             F := Prod;                -- <------- Problem area
             Prod := Prod * F;
             Calc((N-1), F);
          end if;
       end Calc;
       ----------------------------------    
    N : Integer;
    F : Float;

    begin
       Put("Get an integer: ");
       Get(N);
       Put("Get ");
       Put(N, Width => 0);
       Put(" floats: ");
       Calc(N, F);
    end Recprac3;
```

Comment: You need to figure out what is the job of F and Prod. For instance, Prod is undefined, but you display it when N=0 and you erase the value of F with it otherwise...

Comment: Your solution seems to be half-way between producing the result at the innermost recursion and returning (out-parameter) the result from the recursion. You have to decide which one you want

Comment: @Zerte Yeah perhaps I need to try a different method of solving the problem...

Comment: @egilhh If I understand correctly I have to make two functions or procedures then? One that calculates the incoming floats and one that puts the result out? Is it possible to have my solution now as it is with Get(F) and calculate in the same recursion?

Comment: One function, or one procedure (with an appropriate `in out` parameter) will do the job.

Comment: The procedure that puts the result out is `Ada.Float_Text_IO.Put`, but you should call it from the main program after the call to `Calc` returns (by the way, `Calc` is *not* a helpful name! something like maybe `Product` would be better. And, don’t you think the parameter `N` should be `Positive`?). What is `F` for? Presumably it’s to return the product, in which case the one thing you should **not** do in `Calc` is to `Get(F)`. `Get(Tmp)` and then decide what to do with it.

Comment: I can’t remember the last time I used recursion 'for real', but it seems to me it’s easier to think about with a function than with a procedure.

Comment: @Zerte, you can do it with just an `out` parameter

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so let's break things down from the requirements, "*The program is supposed to take N amount of floats and multiply them together, all using recursion.*":

1. Get an integer, N, from the user.
2. Get N number of floats, from the user.
3. Multiply the N floats, using recursion.
4. [Implied] Display the result of the previous requirement.

Well, an obvious way to hold some number of items is the `Array` construct; now, Ada has two forms of this: the constrained and unconstrained, where the former has some definite length. Given that we are getting N from the user we cannot use the definite form.

So, we use something like: `Type Vector is (Integer range <>) of Integer;`.

Ada also gives some interesting attributes: `Length`, `First`, `Last`, `Pred`, `Succ`, and so on. There is also the notion of a "null range", which applied to an Array would indicate a length of zero; this gives us a good base case.

```
-- There IS a bug here, you have to find it.
Function Multiply( Input : Vector ) return Float is
   Subtype Internal is Integer 
      range Integer'Succ(Input'First)..Integer'Pred(Input'Last);
Begin
   Return (if Input'Length not in Positive then 1.0
           else Input(Input'First) * Input(Input'Last) * Multiply(Input(Internal))
          );
End;
```

Next, there's the problem of getting input, validating it, and using it; assuming there are functions of the form `Function Input return Integer`, and the same for `Float`, we could handle #1 and #2 in a single function:

```
Function Input return Float is
Begin
    Loop
        Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line( "Input a value:" );
        declare
            Text : String renames Ada.Text_IO.Get_Line;
        begin
            return Float'Value( Text );
        -- SOMETHING GOES HERE.
        end;
    end loop;
end Input;

Function Results return Vector is
Begin
   Return Result : Vector(1..Input):= (others => Input);
End;
```

That should be enough for you to complete your mission.

**Note:** Constructs herein will have to be adapted for your use.